# Solving systems (?) of equations

Tags: equation-solving

I've been working on my school project. I'm new to Mathematica. This is a part of my Physics demonstration, I want my program to do something until tmax. Where tmax is the positive and real solution from these equations below. I want to pick a solution that real and positive from

```
-15==-10+(1/2) t^2
-15==-10-(1/2) t^2
```

**Question:** How to solve these equations with those conditions?
I try with this one:[image]

but doesn't work

Comment: Try `Solve[{-15 == -10 + (1/2) t^2 , -15 == -10 - (1/2) t^2}, t]`. It returns {}. {} means that there's no solution, which is the truth.

Answer (score 1):

If you add 15 to both sides of both equations you end up with 5+(1/2)t^2 = 0 for the first equation which has no real solution because t^2 >= 0 for all real t.

Comment: actually, the formula is -15==-10+(1/2) a t^2, which we can manipulate a

Comment: @J.Manopo - people can only respond to what you wrote, they cannot be expected to guess what you meant to write. For your revised equation, use `sol = Solve[{-15 == -10 + 1/2 a t^2, t > 0, Element[a, Reals]}, 
   t][[1]]` which evaluates to `{t -> ConditionalExpression[Sqrt[10]*Sqrt[-(1/a)], a < 0]}`

Comment: thank you so much